# Handle async exceptions with task continuation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I've read several articles about handling async exceptions in TPL, most of them suggest using async/await keywords and a regular Try/Catch block around that. I'm stuck with VS-2010 and .NET 4.0 for now, so I tried this code:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class frmMain
  Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object,
                           e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As New Task(AddressOf DoWork)
    Dim t2 As Task = t.ContinueWith(AddressOf MyExceptionHandler,
                                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
    t.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub MyExceptionHandler(t As Task)
    t.Exception.Handle(Function(e As Exception) True) 'ignore all exceptions
  End Sub

  Private Sub DoWork()
    Throw New Exception("Error happened")
  End Sub
End Class
```

If I do `t.Start()`, like the above, it never reaches `MyExceptionHandler`, and just throws an unhandled exception in `DoWork`. If I instead call `t2.Start()`, `DoWork` is never called. How should I do it then?

**Note:** I do not intend to leave my production code like this, the above code sample is just a reduced test case for the issue I am trying to solve. In a real application, the exception will be handled properly.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `MyExceptionHandler` won't be called? The debugger may break in `DoWork` and you'd need to continue it to enter `MyExceptionHandler`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yep, I removed a breakpoint in DoWork before trying it.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Oh, you are right actually, debugger is a problem, even without a breakpoint. I need to continue on exception to make it work. Is there any way to make it auto-continue (i.e. be properly handled)?

Comment: @Neolisk Debug → Exceptions → untick thrown for CLR excpetions.

Comment: @svick: It's unticked already. Only user unhandled is ticked, and the problem is that it is considered unhandled in this case.

Comment: @Neolisk, If I recall correctly, I think that the "Just my code" setting affects this as well.  Try turning off "Just my code".

Comment: @MattSmith: Yep, then it works, however your debugging experience becomes worse, even when working single-threaded. Check this article: [VS2010 On the Impacts of Debugging with “Just My Code”](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2010/07/05/VS2010-On-the-Impacts-of-Debugging-with-Just-My-Code.aspx), and specifically this part: **Step Into “Debugging Experience” with JMC**. I verified it to work exactly as mentioned. So your `Step In` silently becomes a `Step Over`. Bottom line is that disabling Just My Code solves this problem, but introduces another one. Is there another way around it?

Comment: @Neolisk, I read the link.  I didn't find it compelling, as I wouldn't use any of the features he listed (so I keep it disabled).  As far as this exception case is concerned, the JMC feature here is acting "as designed".  *Just your code* didn't handle the exception, other code is handling it.  That said, I too would be interested in a workaround to it if there is one.

Comment: @MattSmith: How are you fighting the `Step In` issue? Expect it to land in a certain place in your program and have a break point there before you do it? Are there any other issues your encountered when JMC is disabled?

Comment: @Neolisk, Yes (in fact, I never expected nor wanted the ability that when I try to step into some code I can't debug that it magically steps into the first part of "my code" that it hits).  I haven't run into any issues (though, I wasn't aware at all of this "issue").